# Setup DNS on Windows Server 2012 with DHCP running router connected to it

Tags: windows-server-2012, dhcp, internal-dns, dhcp-server

I have a Cisco router connected to a server running a fresh installation of Windows Server 2012.

What should I do to configure DNS on the server if I leave the DHCP enabled on the Cisco router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have DHCP from any source you like.  If you have active directory in your environment its much better to have dns running on the AD server and have the clients register themselves in DNS. The only benefit that you would get from keeping DHCP on the windows server is that you can have DHCP register clients that don't auto register.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here, you can configure DNS on the router/firewall if it can, or you can enable DNS on the Windows 2012 Server and let that handle it. Personally, I prefer to have both those functionalities in the same spot, so I would check if the Cisco (assuming its an ASA) has that available, and if it's an ASA, it should.

Comment: If he's using AD, he'll want dns on the windows server.

Answer (score 0):

Since DNS is required to set up AD, this decision must be resolved before installing and configuring AD.  The setup wizard for Windows Server defaults to installing DNS on the first AD server in the forest, along with the AD role.

This is a necro'd question, but if anyone has this question, the best recommendation is to let Windows set up your DNS with the server when you add the AD role.  Personally, I prefer managing DHCP through the Windows interface, so I would move that to the same Windows server.

Bottom line, AD requires DNS, it does not require DHCP.  If you prefer managing DNS on a Linux host, and many do, just be sure to have the details available when you set up your AD so that AD will tie to DNS correctly.  If you intend to have DHCP in your environment, set it up where it makes the most sense for your environment.